# Distcp to S3 OK but cant list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket, distcp

Basically I'm using the command ´distcp´ to put some data in S3, pretty small files.
I am sending the data into a bucket, and a put the files inside a folder of the bucket.

It works fine and I can see on the logs that something has been written to S3 and if I do an `ls` on the bucket I can see the size of the bucket is exactly the same of the data written on the logs:

```
            S3A: Number of bytes read=0

            S3A: Number of bytes written=609

            S3A: Number of read operations=11

            S3A: Number of large read operations=0

            S3A: Number of write operations=5


  DistCp Counters

            Bytes Copied=609

            Bytes Expected=609

            Files Copied=1
```

The issue is that if I `ls` on the folder inside the bucket it's empty, I can't see the file and unsure why.